# Split String with different delimiters at once

Tags: java, android, string

I'm getting one string from the server and want to split it, to set different colors using `SpannableStringBuilder`.

For example, I'm getting strings like:

```
" Hi Mr Xyz, Please visit [Paris::FRANCE] and [Rome::ITALY] once."
```

and I want to set different color to **Paris** and **Rome**. I'm able to split get Paris and Rome separate using :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\]]+)]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(wholeString);
while (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

But how to split main string??

Comment: Maybe you can use a [`replaceAll("\\[([^\\]:]+)::([^\\]]*)]", "<color name="$2">$1</color>")`](https://regex101.com/r/aG4tO9/1)? :) Well, another option is to use this regex with `appendReplacement` to use the `Paris` and `Rome` to search for a corresponding color code.

Comment: just subtract the found string out of the original one?

Comment: but I want to set different colors for Paris and Rome

Comment: @Akshay ,  read the first comment

Comment: @Vyacheslav bro the comment get edited when I was putting mine.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
String wholeString = " Hi Mr Xyz, Please visit [Paris::FRANCE] and [Rome::ITALY] once.";
             Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\]]+)]");
             Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(wholeString);
             while (matcher.find())
             {
                 for (int i = 0; i < matcher.group(1).split("::").length; i++) {
                     System.out.println(matcher.group(1).split("::")[i]);
                }
             }
```